# Wildcard search for get command of Winscp

Tags: winscp

[EDIT]: I am a newbie in using winscp get command.

Lets say I have multiple files in this format

```
ABC_ddMMyyyy.mmss.123.xml and ABC_ddMMyyyy.mmss.234.xml
```

where ddMMyyyy represent today's date

What is the correct command to retrieve all the files?

I figure out that using this

`get /remote_path/*.xml C:\Users\christ\Documents\` is not a good idea because I only want to retrieve today date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think, that it is not a good idea? Looks good to me.

Comment: ah I forgot to mention that I only want to extract today date